# C#, как ввести текст на сайте?

Tags: c#

Допустим, есть сайт www.youtube.com. Как в С# отправить текст в поле поиска, нажать клавишу «Найти» и вывести со страницы название ролика, содержащее текст после `видео=`?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Если Вам "ну очень надо", потрудитесь внятно объяснить, чего Вы хотите. "есть сайт www.youtube.com" - где?

Comment: Если внутри UI C#, то смотрите классы WebBrowser, WebRequest и WebResponse. В остальном конкретизируйте свой вопрос для более точного ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Вам следует ознакомится с youtube api, всё будет значительно проще. Поиск и списки, всё там присутствует, существуют готовые библиотеки на c#

[developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet](http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet)

там есть заголовок "Search by keyword" готовый код, к вашему вопросу.

А если говорить об универсальном средстве, то нужно копать в сторону POST и GET запросов вам изучить основы html и компоненты "webclient и http request".

В ответ на request(в котором содержится форма с input,куда вы вставили название ролика) вам вернется html с кучей роликов, после чего вы будете парсить по какому-то признаку, возможно  или чему-то подобному, в котором будет title, банальным split[] и indexOf() вы вытащите нужный заголовок. Но лучше используйте апи.